# How to sum up only specific values in group by

Tags: sql, group-by, sas

I have the following data

```
Name Place Stores Sales
A X1 10 $100
A X2 20 $150
B X2 25 $200
B X3 30 $300
B X4 40 $400
C X1 30 $300
D X2 40 $400
D X3 50 $500
```

I want to get the Group By Statement to give Name wise Sum of Stores, Sales and Count of Observations (for that Name) only if Stores in that observation are > 20.

So in this example A will not be there in the result at all. Sum of B will be there only with stores 25 and 30 and so on.

How to write SQL query for this.

Comment: so is name or place observation? or does it have it's own rules?  perhaps `Select name,  Sum(Stores), sum(Sales), count(Place) as Observations
From data
Where stores > 20
group by name`

Answer (score 2):

Use a WHERE statement with the clause defining your filter criteria. WHERE occurs before GROUP BY.

```
proc sql;
title 'My Query';
select Name, sum(Stores) as TotalStores
   from sql.mydata
   where Stores > 20
   group by Name, TotalStores;
```